# Custom Domain "Not Found"

Tags: heroku

I have the frontend hosted on Netlify and I also bought my domain there. Now I am trying to add the same domain to my backend that's hosted on Heroku, but I keep getting "Not Found" on the website I set. (I have my frontend on mydomain.com, and would like to have the backend on api.mydomain.com or mydomain.com/api/)

What I did:

1. Through Heroku CLI used the command "heroku domains:add www.mydomain.com" - That worked fine
2. I copied the "abunchofstuffhere.herokudns.com" that I got from the previous command and added it into the Netlify DNS through a CNAME, putting the name to "api" and value to "abunchofstuffhere.herokudns.com", as it said on the Heroku docs.

Now, I'm not sure, if that's all I have to do or if I did something wrong there already, but it definitely isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host `api.mydomain.com` on Heroku, you need `heroku domains:add api.mydomain.com`. Not `www`.

Comment: I did that, did not work sadly. Do you think it might be because Netlify has a free SSL, but on Heroku it says the website is http instead of https?

Comment: You should be wary of DNS TTL; it may take several hours or days for your records changes to have an effect if you have a high TTL. It'd help if you could show us the real domain and a screenshot of your Heroku domains section of their console.